# Utilizar end dentro de una funcion

Tags: python, python-2.7

No puedo utilizar **end**  dentro de la funcion **print**.
Estoy utilizando la version 2.7 de python.

Ejemplo:

```
for i in range(10):
     print("el numero es " + str(i), end=" ")
```

Necesito que no me realice el salto de linea y se imprima en la misma linea

Comment: No esta muy claro lo que necesitas. Quieres que te imprima "El numero es ..." 10 veces todo en una sola linea?

Comment: Si ,es que "print" me lo imprime con salto de linea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de realizar lo que buscas.
La forma mas fácil es la siguiente

```
>>> import sys
>>> for i in xrange(10):
...     sys.stdout.write("El numero es:" + str(i))
... iiiiiiiiii
```

Otra forma es usando un backspace con "\b"

```
>>> for i in xrange(10):
>>> print '\bi'
... iiiiiiiiii
```

Si tienes conocimientos de ingles en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499073/printing-without-newline-print-a-prints-a-space-how-to-remove) puedes encontrar y probar varias formas.

Me avisas cualquier duda o problema.

Comment: Gracias ! :) 

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido Santiago! Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Otra posibilidad es traerse el `print` desde el *futuro* (aunque ya es presente desde hace mucho):

```
from __future__ import print_function

for i in range(10):
     print("el numero es " + str(i), end=" ")
```